# How to enable/disable lock screen from shell script when a special wifi SSID is present?

Tags: shell, lineageos, automation, scripts, bash

My Java skills are low, but I'm mastering shell.

Is use LineageOS 14.1 (forked from cyanogenmod).

I would like to create a shell script on a rooted devive to enable/disable lockscreen (PIN).

I would like to unlock my screen at home when a special SSID is present.

I'm able to discover my known network by running :

```
#!/bin/bash

iw dev wlan0 scan | grep MY_SSID
```

Now, is there a command line to disable/enable the PIN based lock screen depending of the output of this command please ?

Maybe something based on

```
am <something> <stop|start>
```

Tried to make a diff from `ps` with and without lockscreen, but I only have `cyanogenmod.snap` as diff, tried to kill the process, but still the lockscreen.

Any hint please ?

Comment: Not directly answering you but this is trivial with Tasker: https://forums.androidcentral.com/ambassador-guides-tips-how-tos/562081-how-tasker-marshmallow-unlock-when-connected-wifi.html

Comment: Thanks but I prefer a CLI or free solution, I don't have play store to buy paid apps. There's  another apps like this, but seems not trusted sources and weird warnings/limitations

Answer (score 0):

The script below is a partial solution. Partial because it will not disable the Pin. What it does is to wake the device up when it is connected to a chosen wifi, input your password and unlock it.

```
#!/system/bin/sh

mySSID="no wifi present"

connected_wifi()
{
    #Get the network
    mySSID=`dumpsys netstats | awk -F '[/=|,]' '/iface/ {print $8}' | head -1`

}


echo 'Start running script\n\n'

connected_wifi

while true
do
#Check if connected to wifi or mobile data. If connected string is not empty
    if [ "$mySSID" != '' ]
    then

        if [ "$mySSID" == "YourHomeSSID" ] #connected to home wifi
        then

            echo "Connected to $mySSID\n"
            #Check if the screen is on or off
            screen_status=`dumpsys power | awk -F '[/=]' '/Display Power/ {print $2}'`

            if [ "$screen_status" == "OFF" ]
            then
                echo 'The screen is off, Will now input the password'
                #Press the power button to switch the screen on
                input keyevent 26
                #Simulate swipe up gesture
                input touchscreen swipe 320 940 320 100
                #Input your PIN. Change XXXX with your PIN
                input text XXXX 
                #Simulate OK/Enter
                input keyevent 66

            fi

        fi


    fi #not connected to wifi nor mobile data

    #Wait for 3 seconds, then check again if connected to home wifi
    sleep 3
    connected_wifi 

done
```

The main disadvantage of the script is that the screen will be on nearly all the time when connected to your home wifi. To stop the script from running, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from the terminal.

My phone doesn't have `iw` command. I had to use `dumpsys netstats` to get the networkID.